# Using Electronic Cash Register interface to communicate with credit card terminal

Tags: communication

Does anyone know where can I find any kind of technical documentation on Electronic Cash Register interface (ECRi).

It's supposed to be a standard for semi-integrated scenarios, where external application (POS) communicates with a credit card terminal using relatively simple commands (like start sale for $100), without having access to any sensitive credit card details (thus no need for PCI certification).

VeriFone Vx820 Duet is one of the terminals that implements this standard.

I assume communication is performed over TCP/IP, but I can't find anything more.

Is this really a standard, or just a common name for this kind of integration?

Are terminal vendors responsible for this kind of API -or- rather it is some application, that exposes this functionality, and is uploaded to the terminal by specific merchant/bank?

Comment: Pawel Lesnikowski did you figure this out for USA POS ECR-EFT  systems? I am looking to solve a similar problem. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of standards for ECR-EFT integrations, but there is no single protocol guaranteed to be implemented on both POS terminal and ECR side.
Generally, recognized standards are:

- [Polish FROB protocol](https://ecreft.frob.pl/) - the one you're probably asking about is the new polish standard by Fundacja Rozwoju Obrotu Bezgotówkowego, which is supposed to become a part of ECR fiscal certification. You can register for free at the website and access the repository w/ code snippets, simulators and specifications. Kindly note, that the work on specs is still in progress so it may be subject to change. There were also minor bugs in simulators implementation at the time we were working on our own integration project, maybe something has changed since then.
- Nexo - European approach to ECR-EFT unification
- OPI - Open Payment Initiative
- ZVT - German standard, far exceeding scope of current integrations
- on the polish market there are a lot of semi-semi-standards, as a lot of ECR manufacturers implement each others proprietary protocols. There are options to implement only a few of them to gain a significant market coverage, but for that you'll have to do your own research and check with customer needs.

Let me know, if you have questions regarding specific markets or usages

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have probably mentioned it in my question, but I'm interested in US solutions only (or rather hoped there is a single well established international standard)